# SSL Mode=Require causes an error in Npgsql when connecting to pgBouncer

Tags: npgsql, pgbouncer, azure-postgresql

I have an old application which uses Npgsql Version 4.1.12

I am connecting to an Azure database which requires an SSL connection.

I can connect to the database using the string:

```
Server=xxxxx.postgres.database.azure.com;Port=5432;User Id=user;Password=password;Database=test;CommandTimeout=120;Pooling=False;SSL Mode=Require;
```

When I add pgBouncer in Azure and change the port to 6432, I get an error:

```
{"08P01: unsupported startup parameter: ssl_renegotiation_limit"}
```

The application is on .NET Framework 4.7.2 so I am unable to update the Npgsql version.

When I use Npgsql Version 8.0, I don't get the error (and strangely I don't need to add SSL Mode=Require to the connection string.)

Comment: What is the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later versions of Npgsql - including 8.0 - still target .NET Standard 2.0, which means they should be usable from .NET Framework. That's probably what you want to do.